# Javascript localization doesn't load. How to Internationalize javascript without plugin?

Tags: theme-development, javascript, localization

The internationalisation of my theme is defined in `functions.php` and the javascript file to be internationalised uses the `wp-i18n` library.
The translation function `__('string',text-domain');` is recognised correctly and the default language (fr) is displayed correctly. But the translation is never found by the `wp_set_script_translations()` function when `en_GB` language is `localeData`.

The internationalization works perfectly with php for my custom theme and plugins !Also my custom translation plugin works perfectly with `en_GB`.

What files is used to read translation : textdomain-loc_ale-md5.json file or textdomain-loc_ale.po and textdomain-loc_ale.mo files  ?

**wp_set_script_translations()**:  Is it possible to call `wp_set_script_translations()` inside functions.php (theme folder)? If yes, does I make a mistake In my code ?
Does "init" is the good action hook to use to load `wp_set_script_translations()` from the theme folder ? I tried to add and move slash to the directory of file.js and languages folder but it's still not working.

**json file** : Should the -{md5} part of the json file name be kept or can something else be used, from theme folder?

**json parameters** : What do the elements `"domain": "messages"` and `"locale_data":{"messages":{"":{"domain": "messages","lang":"en_GB",..` in the json file script correspond to or refer to? Should "messages" be replaced by "text-domain"? If yes , how to filled this element directly from Cli-Command and why it's not filled automatically ?

The official documentation of i18n doesn't talk about that.

Theme/script/file.js :

```
var localeData = $('html').prop('lang');
localeData = localeData.replace('-', '_'); //return en_GB
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const textdomain = 'text-domain';
__( '__', 'ActivUs' );
wp.i18n.setLocaleData(localeData,'text-domain');
```

Theme/functions.php :

```
add_filter('locale', 'getnewlocale');
function getnewlocale($locale) {
    $gen_locale = explode('/',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[1];
     if ( !is_admin() ) {
        $locale = ($gen_locale == 'fr') ? 'fr_FR' : (($gen_locale == 'en') ? 'en_GB' : '' );
        return $locale;
    }
}

add_action("after_setup_theme", function () {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'text-domain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}, 5);

add_action( 'init', 'js_load_text_domain' );
function js_load_text_domain() {
    wp_set_script_translations( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/script/file.js', 'text-domain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/');
}
// get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages'
```

Files in the "Theme/languages" folder :

```
text-domain-en_GB-md5.json
en_GB.mo
en_GB.po
text-domain.pot
```

Example of Theme/languages/en_GB.po file:

```
#: script/file.js:969
#: script/file.js:2094
msgid "Revenir à la page précédente"
msgstr "Go back to previous page"
```

-------------**UPDATE**-------------

All my javascript files from theme folder were called inside `header.php` and `footer.php`.
To get $handle for my `file.js` inside theme folder I had to decide to enqueue this one like that :

```
function actionjs_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-action', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/file.js', array('jquery', 'wp-i18n' ), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'actionjs_enqueue_scripts' );
```

My $handle ("id" of file.js) is `'main-action'`.

According to the documentation it seems necessary to call the Hook of `wp_set_script_translations()` after enqueued script like that (priority = 100):

```
function load_js_text_domain(){
    wp_set_script_translations( 'main-action', 'text-domain', get_stylesheet_directory().'/languages');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_text_domain', 100 );
```

At the moment I'm not sure of anything as the translation is still not loading.

How can I check that the `.json` or `.po` file is being read? Check that the name of the json file is correct? I've tried so many combinations.

I still don't know which file is read for translation. Is it `text-domain-en_GB-my-handle.json` or `en_GB.po`?

1-If it's the `.json` file, do I have to add the translation by hand from the `.po` file that's already been translated?

2-Why doesn't the make-json command do this automatically (cli-command)? However, I see that the source of .json file is the /script/file.js.

3-Does wp_set_script_translations automatically decode the json or do I have to use json_decode()?
This is how a value in the json file looks like :

`"Revenir \u00e0 la page pr\u00e9c\u00e9dente":[""]`

Must I filled that `[""]`? If I add ["Go to the previous page"], nothing happens !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good News after 2 days!

I resolved my issue, but I believe that `wp i18n make-json` does not generate the json file correctly. Why?

Because it uses the ISO codes and not the locale (get_locale()) from the browser/user. So it isn't "en_GB" that should be used but "en" in the .json file.

This :

`"locale_data": {"messages": { "lang": "en_GB",...`

should be :

`"locale_data": {"messages": { "lang": "en",...`.

That means that you can't distinguish between 'en_US' and 'en_GB'.
So it makes no sense to name these files (.po and .json) with the locale (en_GB) if json use only ISO 639 to retrieve used language.

As a reminder : Language_Country (en_GB) correspond to Language[[ISO 639]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/fr:Liste_des_codes_ISO_639-1)_country[[ISO 3166]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/fr:ISO_3166-1#Table_de_codage).

I also think it's a pity, even if the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Internationalization#localized_string_selection) specifies it, that `wp i18n make-json` (Cli Command) should automatically generate the name of the json file based on the files (at least for Wordpress) that already exist and assuming you already have a `.pot` and `.po` file.

For example, from these files: Awesome.pot , fr_FR.po, en_GB.pot with "Awesome" as the text-domain, obtain: Awesome-en_GB-md5.json and Awesome-fr_FR-md5.json.

Here the script to use to javascript internationalization for a script from the theme folder:

**Theme/script/file.js doesn't change.** see in the original question.

**Files inside Theme/languages folder doesn't change.**

**Theme/functions.php :**

```
function actionjs_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-action', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script/action.js', array('jquery', 'wp-i18n' ), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'actionjs_enqueue_scripts' );

function load_js_text_domain(){
    wp_set_script_translations( 'main-action', 'your-text-domain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_text_domain', 100 );

add_action("after_setup_theme", function () {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'your-text-domain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
});
```

The script for `text-domain-en_GB-md5.json` file looks like this :

```
{
    "translation-revision-date": "2023-09-14 19:28+0200",
    "generator": "WP-CLI\/2.8.1+infong1.1.2",
    "source": "script\/action.js",
    "domain": "your-text-domain",
    "locale_data": {
        "messages": {
            "": {
                "domain": "your-text-domain",
                "lang": "en", // And not "en_GB", only ISO 639
                "plural-forms": "nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);"
            },
            "Ville principale": [
                "Main town"
            ],
```